# SSRS Report Builder Filtering in textbox

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Piewk.png)

I have this report and my query returns this:

```
ReportDate | AMPM | MaxData1 | MaxData2 | MaxData3
2016-04-01 | AM   | 1        | 2        | 3
2016-04-02 | AM   | 5        | 6        | 7
2016-04-03 | AM   | 8        | 9        | 10
2016-04-01 | PM   | 11       | 12       | 13
2016-04-02 | PM   | 14       | 14       | 15
2016-04-03 | PM   | 24       | 24       | 25
```

I need to show the AM data in the AM column textbox in my report and the PM in the PM column textbox.  I couldn't find a filter on the textbox properties.  I'm using Report Builder 3.0

Comment: What is team and where is this in your data? What is A and B and where is this in your data?

Comment: Team is generated based on a Data point.  You can ignore that.  A and B can also be ignored.

Comment: OK and you are not using the date column in your report? What is your expected value for Data 1 under AM? 1, 5, 8 or the sum of these?

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way to do this sort of filtering on the report columns or textboxes.   The usual way to do this is to have your SQL return both an AM column and a PM column.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to do that?  It just makes my query twice as big...

Comment: Add your query to your question and I'll tell you how I would change it.